# Python Pandas to R dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

I am going to convert Python pandas dataframe to dataframe in R.
I found out few libraries for this problem

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html

which is rpy2

But I couldn't find the methods for saving or transfer it to R.

Firstly I tried "to_csv"

```
df_R = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(df_total)
df_R.to_csv(direc+"/qap/detail_summary_R/"+"distance_"+str(gp_num)+".csv",sep = ",")
```

But it gives me an error

```
"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_csv'  "
```

So I tried to see its data type
it was

```
<class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame'>
```

how could I save this type object to csv file or transfer to R?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The recent documentation https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/generated_rst/pandas.html has a section about interacting with `pandas`.

Otherwise objects of type `rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame` have a method `to_csvfile`, not `to_csv`:

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/vector.html#rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame.to_csvfile

If wanting to pass data between Python and R, there are more efficient ways than writing and reading CSV files. Try the conversion system:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

base = importr('base')
# call an R function on a Pandas DataFrame
base.summary(my_pandas_dataframe)
```

Answer (score 20):

If standard text-based formats (csv) are too slow or bulky, I'd recommend [feather](https://github.com/wesm/feather), a serialization format built on [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/). It was explicitly developed by the creators of RStudio/ggplot2/etc (Hadley Wickham) and pandas (Wes McKinney) for performance and interoperability between Python and R (see [here](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/)).

You need pandas verson 0.20.0+, `pip install feather-format`, then you can use the `to_feather`/`read_feather` operations as drop-in replacements for `to_csv`/`read_csv`:

```
df_R.to_feather('filename.feather')
df_R = pd.read_feather('filename.feather')
```

The `R` equivalents (using the package `feather`) are

```
df <- feather::read_feather('filename.feather')
feather::write_feather(df, 'filename.feather')
```

Besides some minor tweaks (e.g. you can't save custom DataFrame indexes in feather, so you'll need to call `df.reset_index()` first), this is a fast and easy drop-in replacement for `csv`, `pickle`, etc.

**EDIT**: Today (Juni 2022) the feather development moved to arrow. It means don't use `feather` library but `arrow`.

```
library(arrow)
df <- arrow::read_feather('filename.feather')
```

Comment: As of March 2020, feather / pyarrow does not support dataframes wrapping sparse matrices.

Comment: Does it need to write to disk, or it is possible to use it to serialize from python to binary or text (e.g. a field in a SQL server table) and deserialize to R?

Answer (score 7):

Once you have your data.frame you can save it using `write.table` or one of the wrappers of the latter, for example `writee.csv`.

#### In rpy2 :

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
## get a reference to the R function 
write_csv = robjects.r('write.csv')
## save 
write_csv(df_R,'filename.csv')
```